# How to show / hide TR elements that are not empty / empty

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to show my TR elements when they are not empty using CSS only. This code will be used for email.

Initially I have their display as none and as the data fills in I want to show the table rows that have content and make the other rows that do not have content disappear.

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">table, td { color: #000000; } a { color: #236fa1; text-decoration: underline; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .u-row {
    width: 600px !important;
  }
  .u-row .u-col {
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .u-row .u-col-100 {
    width: 600px !important;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .u-row-container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .u-row .u-col {
    min-width: 320px !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
  .u-row {
    width: calc(100% - 40px) !important;
  }
  .u-col {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .u-col > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.ie-container table,
.mso-container table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.assig-detail:not(:empty) {
  display:none;
}
* {
  line-height: inherit;
}

a[x-apple-data-detectors='true'] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

p:empty){
line-height:0px;
font-size:0px;
height:0px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#ArtBio1:not(:empty){
  display:block !important;
}

#ArtBio2:not(:empty){
  display:block !important;
}

#ArtBio3:not(:empty){
  display:block !important;
}

#ArtBio4:not(:empty){
  display:block !important;
}

#ArtBio5:not(:empty){
  display:block !important;
}

</style>
```

My HTML:

```
<tr id="ArtBio1" style="border-collapse:collapse; display:none;">
         <td style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:33px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:25px;background-color:transparent" bgcolor="tansparent" align="left">
          <!--[if mso]><table style="width:560px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]-->

          <!--[if mso]></td><td style="width:20px"></td><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]-->
          <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left">
               <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px">
                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                   <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                    <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><p class= "assignmentTitle-1" style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong style="line-height:150%">[question("option value"), id="136", option="10766", stringformat="&#8226;  %s"]</strong></span></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="218",stringformat='&#9702;    Artist Name: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="219", stringformat='&#9702;    Project Title: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="220", stringformat='&#9702;    Target Delivery Date: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="146", stringformat='&#9702;    PO #: %s']</p>
                    </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                    <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="center">
                     <table width="580px;" height="0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                     </table></td>
                   </tr>
                 </table></td>
               </tr>
             </table>
           </td>
           </tr>

           <tr id="ArtBio2" style="border-collapse:collapse; display:none;">
            <td style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:33px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:25px;background-color:transparent" bgcolor="tansparent" align="left">
              <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left">
                               <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px">
                                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                                   <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                    <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><p class= "assignmentTitle-1" style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong style="line-height:150%">[question("option value"), id="136", option="10767", stringformat="&#8226;  %s"]</strong></span></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="222",stringformat='&#9702;    Artist Name: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="223", stringformat='&#9702;    Project Title: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="224", stringformat='&#9702;    Target Delivery Date: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="220", stringformat='&#9702;    Target Delivery Date: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="148", stringformat='&#9702;    PO #: %s']</p>
                                    </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                    <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="center">
                                     <table width="580px;" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                                     </table></td>
                                   </tr>
                                 </table></td>
                               </tr>
                             </table>
                           </td>
                           </tr>

              <tr id="ArtBio3" style="border-collapse:collapse; display:none;">
               <td style="Margin:0;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:33px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:25px;background-color:transparent" bgcolor="tansparent" align="left">
                 <table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left">
                                  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                   <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:300px">
                                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                                      <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                       <td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><p class= "assignmentTitle-1" style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px"><span style="font-size:16px"><strong style="line-height:150%">[question("option value"), id="136", option="10768", stringformat="&#8226;  %s"]</strong></span></p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="226",stringformat='&#9702;    Artist Name: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="227", stringformat='&#9702;    Project Title: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="228", stringformat='&#9702;    Target Delivery Date: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="220", stringformat='&#9702;    Target Delivery Date: %s']</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:'Courier New', monospace;line-height:21px;color:#333333;font-size:14px">[question("value"), id="150", stringformat='&#9702;    PO #: %s']</p>
                                       </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
                                       <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="center">
                                        <table width="580px;" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px">
                                        </table></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                              </tr>
```